# web view not load claims authentication dialog

Tags: authentication, azure, webview, windows-8.1, claims-based-identity

We have a SharePoint website hosted on azure, one which claims authentication is enabled which authenticate from ADFS. We had issues authenticating user when user having Direct Access enabled. So to resolve that, we added website in IE trusted sites, enforced from IT policies. This issue is resolved and site redirection started working.

Now we have a windows 8.x app, which also does similar authentication. But webview is not able to load authentication dialog.
[image]

Below is URL trace -

When connected

https://siteonline.com/

https://siteonline.com/_layout/15/authentication.aspx

https://siteonline.com/_layout/si/login.aspx

https://siteonline.com/v2/wsfederation

https://siteonline.com/adfs/ls

https://siteonline.com/adfs/ls/auth/integrated/

When Direct Access enabled –

https://siteonline.com/

https://siteonline.com/_layout/15/authentication.aspx

https://siteonline.com/_layout/si/login.aspx

https://siteonline.com/v2/wsfederation

Does anyone have clue that this problem is with web view or Direct Access configuration?

Does site need to be added as trusted site for web view also? How can we do that?